# C++ variadic templates pass modified arguments to function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, gradient-descent

I'm struggling with the following code. It's meant to be a very simple, hopefully `constexpr`, gradient-descent solver.

My current code looks like this:

```
typedef std::function<double(double, double, double)> residual_function_t;

double gradient_descent(const residual_function_t& res_fun, double step_size, double& x, double& y, double& z,
                        double epsilon = 0.01) {
  assert(step_size > 0.0);

  const auto residual = res_fun(x, y, z);

  const auto deriv_x = (res_fun(x + epsilon, y, z) - residual) / epsilon;
  const auto deriv_y = (res_fun(x, y + epsilon, z) - residual) / epsilon;
  const auto deriv_z = (res_fun(x, y, z + epsilon) - residual) / epsilon;

  x -= std::copysign(step_size, deriv_x);
  y -= std::copysign(step_size, deriv_y);
  z -= std::copysign(step_size, deriv_z);

  return residual;
}
```

I'd like to make the function more general, and accept any kind of function. That means I have to create variables like `deriv_x` for each of the arguments I want to pass to that function.

I'd like my function signature to be something like this:

```
template<typename residual_function_t, typename... Arg_types>
double gradient_descent(const residual_function_t & res_fun, double step_size, Arg_types... arguments) {
constexpr auto epsilon = 0.01;

const auto residual res_fun(arguments...);

// Here I want to calculate deriv_x/y/z/etc for every argument passed.

// Here want to assign x/y/z, or return them if needed, for every argument passed.

return residual;
}
```

I wonder if this is possible? If it makes life easier to assume all arguments are of type `double`, that would also work.

Comment: I would recommend not using a variadic template parameter here.  You know you need 3 elements, and 3 elements exactly so you can just code that in like `template<typename residual_function_t, typename Arg_type> double gradient_descent(const residual_function_t & res_fun, double step_size, Arg_type& x, Arg_type& y, Arg_type& z) `

Comment: 1. This is invalid algorithm. This `std::copysign(step_size` breaks it. Try generalize Newton method. 2. To make this more general, you should compose all coordinates in single class or struct.

Comment: @NathanOliver that's the thing I'd like to generalize into an arbitrary amount of arguments.

Comment: For that type of static for loops, you should try to have a look at C++ 17 [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). Folding over the comma `,` operator lets you map an abritrary expression over a variadic argument pack. The only problem I see is rotating the `epsilon` through the different arguments.

Comment: Any reason not using vector for coordinates?

Comment: @MarekR I realize that. The function I initiallize wanted to solve this for was the intersection of a number of 3D spheres which are very close together. That means that the residual function has a very shallow slope near the minimum. Using newton's derivative made the algorithm jump around the minimum. Hence a fixed step size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the arguments to be of type double, then you might consider using `std::initializer_list` as follows:

```
double gradient_descent(const residual_function_t& res_fun,
                        double step_size,
                        std::initializer_list<double> args,
                        double epsilon = 0.01) {
    // ...
```

The downside is that you have to add an extra set of braces around the `args` when calling the function.  Otherwise, while not strictly required, you may want to move `epsilon` before the variadic argument list to simplify your life.  You have many options for handling a template parameter pack.  One simple thing you can do in C++17 or later is to put the arguments into an array:

```
double gradient_descent(const residual_function_t& res_fun,
                        double step_size,
                        double epsilon,
                        auto ...argspack) {
    std::array<double, sizeof...(argspack)> args(double(argspack)...);
    // ...
}
```

If you want to modify the arguments, that's fine, too, though they have to be doubles at that point:

```
double gradient_descent(const residual_function_t& res_fun,
                        double step_size,
                        double epsilon,
                        std::same_as<double> auto &...argspack) {
    std::array<std::reference_wrapper<double>, sizeof...(argspack)> args(std::as_ref(argspack)...);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think user3188445's answer comes closest, since std::apply also works with an std::array. 
I don't see yet how I'm going to update the passed parameters to the new value (aside from passing them as reference). I need to somehow assign a value to the Nth entry in the parameter pack.

Comment: @RoelBaardman Why can't you just update the array, as in `args[i] *= 1.1`?

Comment: it is my understanding that this would create a copy of the argument pack inside an std::array object.
What I would like to do is pass ```argspack``` by reference and modify them.

Comment: @RoelBaardman no problem, just define the function to take an array `&&...argspack` and `array` as `args(std::as_ref(argspack)...)`.

Comment: Do you mean ```std::ref```? ```std::as_ref``` appears not to be C++, but more a Rust thing.

Comment: @RoelBaardman my bad, yes, [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to create a `reference_wrapper`.  Don't know why I said `as_ref`.